# How can I make SharedPreferences to update the data instead of overwriting the data and losing part of it?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I'm using the following piece of code to save an `ArrayList<String>` into `SharedPreferences`:

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for(String str: semesterArray) {
        stringBuilder.append(str);
        stringBuilder.append(",");
    }

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCES", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("semesterArray", stringBuilder.toString());
    editor.apply();
```

This is somewhat getting the job done since it saves the `ArrayList<String>` as intended and when the app is re-launched the `Semesters` that were added are still stored in the `ArrayList<String>` as I want them to be. But if I add more `Semesters` after re-launching the app, the `Semesters` that were saved are overwritten and I lose the previously saved `Semesters`. Is there a way `SharedPreferences` can be updated instead of overwritten? If not, in what direction should I move to store these `Semesters`? Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your case you need to use  sqlite or another database..

Comment: May I know the reason why I need to do that?

Comment: i guess sharedpreference won't keep old entries , it is going to update them with new data , i guess sharedpreferences are only used for simple storage of data , for that you might consider using sqlite db or room db also which is efficient in storing data

Comment: @JaimeMiranda because by design sharedpreference will overwrite the data

Comment: Didn’t know that. I’m new to Android developing as you can see and I’m really struggling with saving data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comment using sharedPrefences to update or insert new values is not a good practice , but i will give you a solution if you want to use sharedPrefences

what you can do is  :

1. create prefrence called current to save the value of your string
2. create another prefrence called new , to save the new data  after
   checking that it's not equal to the current.

you will end with something like this code :

```
 sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared",MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        String text = "first text";
        editor.putString("current",text);
        if (!sharedPreferences.getString("current","").equals(sharedPreferences.getString("new","")))
        {
            editor.putString("new",sharedPreferences.getString("current","") + text );
            editor.commit();

        }
        editor.commit();
```

> Result after first save  : sharedPreferences.getString("current","")
> will return "some text" and sharedPreferences.getString("new","") will
> return ""
>
> Result after changing "first Text" to " new text" :
> sharedPreferences.getString("current","") will return "new text" and
> sharedPreferences.getString("new","") will return "first text new
> text"

how to use it :

```
  if sharedPreferences.getString("new","") equals ""
your data is not updated  use sharedPreferences.getString("current","")  
else  your data is updated so use sharedPreferences.getString("new","")
```

Comment: I implemented this solution into my code and it's actually duplicating the items. For example, I add (Summer 2020) when I add another Semester now the list is Summer 2020, Summer 2020, and new item added. Any idea why this might be happening?