# Deleting an item (index) from SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I'm saving an array called `semesterArray` which is a `List<String> semesterArray = new ArrayList<>()` with the following method on `SharedPreferences`:

```
public void saveSemesterArray() {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for(String str: semesterArray) {
        stringBuilder.append(str);
        stringBuilder.append(",");
    }

    SharedPreferences currentSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CURRENT", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = currentSharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("currentSemesterArray", stringBuilder.toString());

    if(!currentSharedPreferences.getString("currentSemesterArray", "").equals(
            currentSharedPreferences.getString("updatedSemesterArray", ""))) {
        editor.putString("updatedSemesterArray", currentSharedPreferences.getString(
                "currentSemesterArray", "") + stringBuilder.toString());
        editor.apply();
    }
    editor.apply();
}
```

The **if statement** is there to update the `SharedPreferences`, I got the idea from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62924891/11770758). Now, the following method takes care of loading the `SharedPreferences` that were just saved:

```
public void loadSemesterArray() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("CURRENT", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String semestersString = sharedPreferences.getString("updatedSemesterArray", "");
    String[] itemsSemesters = semestersString.split(",");
    List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    noDuplicates = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < itemsSemesters.length; i++) {
        items.add(itemsSemesters[i]);
    }

    // Removing duplicates from Semesters list
    for(String str: items) {
        if(!noDuplicates.contains(str)) {
            noDuplicates.add(str);
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < noDuplicates.size(); i++) {
        Log.d("NoDuplicatesList", noDuplicates.get(i));
    }
}
```

We remove duplicate Semesters because the **if statement** in the `saveSemesterArray` method duplicates the already saved Semesters into the updated `SharedPreferences`. Now, I want to create a a method that deletes an item (index) from the `SharedPreferences`. For example, if I have **Spring 2020**, **Summer 2020**, and **Fall 2020**, I'd be able to delete any index in that list and save it again so the list is updated. Is there a way this can be done using `SharedPreferences`? If not what should I be using instead? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to remember you're not saving a list into `SharedPreferences`, you're saving a string that serlizes the data in a format that's easy to deserlize.

Second, saving a string into `SharedPreferences` is a very quick task, you don't really need to make an `if` check to make sure they're not exactly the same.

Third, the only way to delete an item from that serlized list would be :

1- Deserlizing the list saved.

2- Removing the item at the index.

3- Reserlizing the list and saving it again.

Comment: The ```if``` statement is there because if the user adds a Semester after closing the application, and the user had previously added Semesters on the previous session, the Semesters added in the previous session will be lost since ```SharedPreferences``` doesn't update the data, it simply overwrites it. So that's why I did that. Anyways, could you point me in the right direction on how to deserialize the list saved? Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Set to store your list. Convert your string array to Set and then save that set to

`sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet(key, value).apply();`

Then query your preference and convert it to list and then you can remove anything by index.

Comment: I don't understand this answer that much, could you explain a little bit more? Thanks!